# executor failed running [/bin/sh -c chmod +x entrypoint.sh]: exit code: 1

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I am adding fastapi to docker which has background tasks. When i am trying to build the docker i am getting this error `executor failed running [/bin/sh -c chmod +x entrypoint.sh]: exit code: 1` .Command using to build docker image `docker build -t onetest .` I have tried removing `RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh`and tried to build build the image but when i run the docker i got this error `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown.`.

`entrypoint.sh`

```py
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker app.main:app
```

`Dockerfile`

```py
FROM python:3.9-slim
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./inputs ./inputs
COPY ./model ./model
COPY ./tests ./tests
COPY ./gunicorn.config.py ./gunicorn.config.py
COPY ./Procfile ./Procfile
EXPOSE 8000
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you `COPY entrypoint.sh .` into your image at all.  "Exit code 1" just means "it didn't work"; is there more to the error message than that?  (Also try running the `chmod` command on your host system and committing the file to source control with execute permissions.)

Comment: Thanks `COPY entrypoint.sh .` solved the problem but after running the docker when i open it i am getting unable to connect `127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`